# Array modifier on parent and all of its children

Tags: workflow, objects, modifiers

I have a parent with a lot of children. I want to use an array modifier on the whole lot of them, including the parent, but, when I add an array modifier to the parent, only it gets duplicated.

One sort-of-solution I found is to Duplicate Link the parent along with its children, but this requires fiddly manual positioning that I'd like to avoid, and I also think this would make it difficult to add a child. The other solution I found is to add an array modifier to the parent and every single child; although this method does what I want in theory, it's still a lot of clicking.

Comment: Do you need the children's array modifiers to update along with the parents

Comment: Are you talking about my second solution? If so, yes.

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/array-a-group-of-objects

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3271/599

Answer (score 2):

Create your parent object, then create one child. copy the array from the parent to the child <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>. next take the child and add drivers to all of the parameters in the array modifier that you want to auto update. now copy the drivers and array modifiers onto all  of the other children. Done!

Using drivers is tricky, Here are some tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4qYHNA_x4Q

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajMAvKRCTBg

[How to copy drivers onto multiple objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3312/how-to-copy-drivers-to-multiple-objects)

Comment: Can you please add some detail? I have never used a driver.

Comment: A bit disappointing that array modifiers don't copy objects with their children but this solution works like  a charm and isn't too hard to set up. @catlover2 Although I know it's more than a year later I still want to mention that [Mastering Drivers](http://exploreblender.com/) has been an excellent resource for me to fully understand drivers in Blender.