# Can I add a driver many bones at the same time?

Tags: bones, drivers

I want to add a driver to a lot of selected bones at the same time, is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to copy drivers to multiple Objects?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3312/how-to-copy-drivers-to-multiple-objects)